# VLC : Error, Unable to save subtitles

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, vlc, downloads, subtitle

I use Ubuntu 18.04 with VLC 3.0.7. Since some time ago, I am not able to automatically download subtitles through VLC. I have to use the *Click here to open the file* option in the error dialogue and download them using Firefox. The subtitles were supposed to be automatically downloaded to the folder in which the video file is located.

I tried setting folder permissions using `chmod` as `777` and `755`. Both failed. Any help will be great.

[image: VLC subtitle window]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It appears the cache subfolder is missing. For Ubuntu Linux just open terminal and run `mkdir ~/.cache/vlc`

Comment: or `mkdir ~/snap/vlc/common/.cache/vlc` if installed by snap

Comment: and don't forget to give write permissions to the newly created folder, `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /home/your_username/.cache/vlc`  (just worked for me on ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa with apt install, I suppose the same should work for snap installs)

Comment: @leomonsaingeon I think - other than safer - you should be fine with `chmod -R chmod -R a+rwx,o-x`/`chmod -R 776` only

Answer (score 2):

Some had to delete an existing vlc folder in the ~/.cache directory, recreate it with mkdir and then restart vlc.

Case you are using the snap, mkdir ~/snap/vlc/common/.cache/vlc .

Answer (score 0):

Ticket and solution is available in github [VLC Subtitle](https://github.com/exebetche/vlsub/issues/213)